How to Create a Timestamped Log File Before Setup Starts in Advanced Installer Bootstrapper?
I am working with Advanced Installer and need to create a dynamically named log file for the installation process. The log file's name should include a timestamp to differentiate between multiple installations. Here's what I want:
The log file name should be generated based on the current date and time, e.g., install_2024-10-17_14-30-45.log
The log should be created before the setup begins to capture all installation events from the very start.
What I’ve Tried So Far:
Using MSI Command Line in Bootstrapper: I added the following to Bootstrapper > MSI Command Line Options:
/L*e "[%ProgramData]\[|Manufacturer]\[|ProductName] [|ProductVersion]\install_[|TIMESTAMP].log"

However, I realized that the Custom Actions or properties such as TIMESTAMP can only be executed after the setup starts, which means I cannot generate the timestamp dynamically at the right time.
Is there a way to dynamically generate a timestamped log file name directly within Advanced Installer’s Bootstrapper without requiring external scripts? Ideally, I’d like the timestamp to be applied to the log before any part of the installation starts to capture all events properly.

To name the log based on your scenario you will have to create an external script, maybe you can even copy the log in a more convenient location. The MSI Command Line field from the Bootstrapper Options only allows pseudo-formatted properties reference. At build time the property references are replaced with the value of the respective properties.
For example, you can take advantage of the MsiLogging property. Windows Installer will automatically set the MsiLogFileLocation property to the full path of the log file. In order to generate an installation log, you can check the Enable Verbose Logging option from the Install Parameters view. By enabling this option, a log file will be generated each time the install package runs.
Then, you can have a custom action at the end of the installation that will copy & rename the log to the desired location and preferred naming convention.
You may need to add a few seconds of delay when your script is running, to give enough time for the log to have all the windows-installer events. After this, you can execute the custom action.
There are a few threads on the Advanced Installer forums explaining how to integrate the custom action, check the Possible to copy the verbose log after install to AppDir for more details.
Let me know if you need any help to sort this out.

Thanks for your guidance but,
Even though I triggered the Custom Action at the Finish Dialogs Stage, I encountered the following error when attempting to move the log file:
"The file is being used by another process."

This issue likely occurs because the Microsoft Installer (MSI) locks the log file during the installation process. In response, I tried copying the log file instead of moving it, with a 2-second delay before the operation. However, the log file still contained incomplete data.
The likely reason for this behavior is that MSI continues to write to the log file until the entire installation process, including the MSI session, has fully closed. Since the Custom Action is triggered before the MSI process completely shuts down, it’s possible that not all log events are captured by the time the log file is copied.

Indeed, you would need to copy the file, the move is not yet available.
Also, you need to disable all the flags so that the MSI continue the installation and not wait for the custom action to complete its execution e.g. disable the "Wait for return code at the end of the sequence" and all related flags:
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-action-properties.html
I would recommend adding about 6-10seconds of delay inside your custom action before trying to move the log file.
